# Compare 2 Skeletons in Kinect

Tags: kinect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing a saved movement with other movement with Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438813/comparing-a-saved-movement-with-other-movement-with-kinect)

I want to create simple game like Dance Central which captures player's skeleton and verifies the accuracy of his gesture. How I can check their skeleton by compare it with my skeleton data (which captured before). Please give me explanation :)

Comment: Exact dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438813/comparing-a-saved-movement-with-other-movement-with-kinect/11442334#11442334

Answer (score 2):

What parts of it do you want to compare? You might want to use [`BoneOrientation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.boneorientation.aspx) to get the angles of the bones. Also the [`Skeleton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeleton_members.aspx) has some identifiers you may want to check out. You could also compare the positions of individual [`Joints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.joint.aspx) to find the bone lengths. Also [Is it possible to save a user's skeleton and facial data for recognition purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210461/is-it-possible-to-save-a-users-skeleton-and-facial-data-for-recognition-purpose) might also be helpful.

You may want to see the [Skeletal Tracking Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973074.aspx), as it provides some pretty good details to your problem.

Comment: This is assuming you are using the SDK of course :)

Comment: yes, I am using the SDK. :)
I want to compare the similarities between two skeletons. Can you tell me how I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438813/comparing-a-saved-movement-with-other-movement-with-kinect/11442334#11442334

Comment: hey @Kinected i am using tha comparison of the joints positions (Hard Job, in progress yet). Have you used bone orientation with success?

Comment: That was just an idea, so no I have not. But I have compared the location of the joints... I did the same thing [Outlaw Lemur](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438813/comparing-a-saved-movement-with-other-movement-with-kinect/11442334#11442334) did, and he explains it well. Basically you want to compare the position, but they wont be the exact same every time, so you need to multiply the coordinates by a certain number to find out what they would be had the skeleton been in the same spot as the original skeleton was recorded in and then you can find the accuracy of the gestures recorded.