# User detection in unity with kinect sdk

Tags: unity-game-engine, wrapper, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using Unity 4.0.1 with kinect sdk 1.6 and developing with c# (imported kinect wrapper),

In the project when user goes out of range or one of bones can not be captured because of user not exactly in the range of kinect I want to display a message.

I've tried "code for detecting humans" in 
[Kinect user Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577862/kinect-user-detection)

This solution gives compile error like

"Assets/Kinect/KinectModelControllerV2.cs(93,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DepthImageFrame' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

I've imported Kinect and tried to import DepthImageFrame to chect if it works, but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you directly copied the code from that post or have you developed it yourself? It's not clear what DepthImageFrame is or where it comes from.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

The examples provided in the [Kinect for Windows Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx) and the code located on the [Kinect for Windows CodePlex](http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/) site are full of examples of how to detect players.

Looking at the "Skeleton Basics" example immediately comes to mind, followed by the "Shape Game" example.

A basic flow to detecting players in the `SkeletonFrameReady` callback follows:

```
Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[6];

private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        if (skeletonFrame != null)
        {
            skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
        }
    }

    if (skeletons.Length != 0)
    {
        foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
        {
            if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                // `skel` is an actively tracked skeleton
                // do what you wish with it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English.

The reason is because the wrapper uses Kinect SDK 1.0 and you use Kinect SDK 1.6.

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Unity-and-the-Kinect-SDK.