# Recognize two skeletons Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-interaction

I have make a game (pong) using a kinect, I can recognize one skeleton and I can make gestures to control the left stick, but when I try to play with two players don´t recognize the skeleton of other player. This is what I do so far:

```
private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (skeletonFrame != null)
                {
                    skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
                }
                if (skeletons.Length != 0)
                {
                    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                    {
                        if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                        {
                            this.tracked(skel);
                            this.trackedLeft(skel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void tracked(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            Joint jHandRight = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
            Joint jHipCenter = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter];
            if ((jHipCenter.Position.Z - jHandRight.Position.Z) > 0.2)
            {
                //Consider hand raised in front of them
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hand: Raised");
                //MessageBox.Show("POR FAVORRRRRRRR");
                //movement[0] = false;
                movement[0] = true;
                movement[1] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Hand is lowered by the users side
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hand: Lowered");
                //MessageBox.Show("A SERRRRIIIIIOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
                //movement[1] = false;
                movement[1] = true;
                movement[0] = false;
            }
        }
```

Someone could help me.

Comment: How do you distinguish between player 1 and 2?

Comment: currently I am not able to distinguish, I read that the kinect can recognize two players ... maybe giving ids but do not know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to distinguish between skeleton one and two. See [Kinect user Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577862/kinect-user-detection/10584231#10584231) for how to do this. You can then pass the skeleton for player one and two to your two different methods. I use the player ID because if a skeleton is lost for a frame or two, their ID remains the same

```
int id1 = 0, id2 = 0;

... 

if (skeletons.Length != 0)
{
    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
    {
         if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
         {
                if (skel.TrackingID == id1)
                    this.tracked(skel);
                else if (skel.TrackingID == id2)
                    this.trackedLeft(skel);
                else
                {
                     if (id1 != 0 && id2 == 0)
                         id2 = skel.TrackingID;
                     else if (id2 != 0 && id1 == 0)
                         id1 = skel.TrackingID;
                }
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean to have both ID's the same?

Comment: @mason No haha accidentally messed up my code... Check my edits

Comment: I have a question, in which case will the code enter this `if (id1 != 0 && id2 == 0)
                         id2 = skel.TrackingID;
                     else if (id2 != 0 && id1 == 0)
                         id1 = skel.TrackingID;`                                        i tried it and it never passes there... am i missing something?

Comment: I found the way to distinguish the two players, thank you for your help :)

Comment: @seal That condition is satisfied when the first id has been assigned (id1) so it is not zero, but id2 still has the starting value of zero, so it assigns the new id to id2