# Knowing nothing about Kinect/NET how hard would it be to get body position data?

Tags: kinect

Friends asked me to help him on a project, and attempting to get a sense for how easy it will be using the Kinect platform to get body positions data using the .NET platform. For example, does Kinect just give a raw datastream of movements within the range of the sensors, or does it have the option to use a "smart" datastream that IDs people, elements of a person, and position changes of people/elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every skeleton that is tracked has its own uniq ID. From skeleton you can get position (axis x,y,z) of every joint that is tracked.
It`s not a simple datastream but complex set of data

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Using the keywords present in your answer I was able to find this video "[Skeletal Tracking Fundamentals](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals)"

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered, but I just wanted to point out that if you see my answer on [Kinect user Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577862/kinect-user-detection/10584231#10584231), you can also use the `PlayerIndex` which JuergeonD also explains on [Kinect SDK player detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562554/kinect-sdk-player-detection/10562574#10562574). Hope this helps!