# real world coordinates in skeleton

Tags: wpf, kinect

What is the real world coordinates in skeleton Tracking using kinect. How to find the exact position.Z for Spine joint

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `SkeletonFrameReady` event to get specific position in each frame:

```
 void _sensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            SkeletonFrame sf = e.OpenSkeletonFrame();

            if (sf != null)
            {
                Skeleton[] allSkeletons = new Skeleton[6];
                sf.CopySkeletonDataTo(allSkeletons);
                Skeleton[] tracked = (Skeleton[]) (
                    from s in allSkeletons
                    where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                    select s
                );

                Skeleton first = (
                    from s in allSkeletons
                    where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                    select s
                ).FirstOrDefault();

                if (first != null)
                {

                   var Spinepos=first.Joints[JointType.Spine].Position.Z;
                }
            }
```

There is an article [Kinect for Windows: Find user height accurately](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380152/Kinect-for-Windows-Find-user-height-accurately) 
also try

1. [Kinect SDK player detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562554/kinect-sdk-player-detection/10562574#10562574)
2. [Kinect user Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577862/kinect-user-detection)

and a good [Kinect Getting Started](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213034/Kinect-Getting-Started-Become-The-Incredible-Hulk) article.