# Kinect Player Detection

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

Hi everyone I've got the following code block

```
using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
    if (skeletonFrame != null)
    {
        Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
        foreach (Skeleton skeleton in skeletons)
        {
            if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                //DoSomething();
            }
            else if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked)
            {
                //DoSomethingElse();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

My plan is to call a method that says player detected when a player is tracked. And the contrary when no one is tracked. In essence using the Kinect for motion detector (only human I know). But as it appears this loop is not working correctly for me. With the help of debugger I can see that I do get inside the `DoSomething();` But thats where its get stuck and keeps repeating the same message that `DoSomething()` supposed to do even when the player leaves.
Any idea why is this happening and how to accomplish this?

Comment: Or is there a way to create an event to fire an event when a player tracked status is changed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kinect SDK player detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562554/kinect-sdk-player-detection)